# Import JavaScript file by embedding with another js file

Tags: javascript, import

How would I import this external [js](https://github.com/benc-uk/k6-reporter/blob/main/dist/bundle.js) file by embedding the contents into another file? The entire JavaScript is wrapped around with an anonymous function using arrow syntax, I thought I would be able to do by removing that and assigning it to a variable

`var bundle = () => { //contents };` or using `export function bundle() {//contents};`

and calling it with `bundle.htmlReport(data)`, but an error is returned citing it cannot find `htmlReport`

JavaScript is not my forte.

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not just links to other sites.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle` does not contain a property htmlReport, nor can it contain that property because it's a function and not an object, if the arrow function returns an object with `htmlReport` as a property then you can do `bundle().htmlReport`